# javascript object how to use 'this'?

Tags: javascript, object, this

This code is working but if I change `N.max` to `this.max` it stops working.
I wonder why it doesn't work

```js
const N = {
  min: function(arr) {
    arr.sort((a, b) => a - b);
    return arr.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a * b / N.max(a, b); // here
    });
  },
  max: (a, b) => (b) ? N.max(b, a % b) : a // and here
}

let arr = [2, 6, 8, 14];

console.log(N.min(arr));
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Comment: specific part of interest: arrow functions. Also, don't break your code by bad comment syntax, it is very hard to read this way.

Answer (score -1):

`this` means 'current object', it is the case that even if you are in `N`, `this` is not referring to that const.

If you want to see what actually are referring using `this`, then as it is javascript, I recommend you to add `console.log(this)`, so you see what `this` is referring to.